# How to apply GROUP_CONCAT in mysql Query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

How to apply `GROUP_CONCAT` in this query?

**Query**

```
SELECT WEEK(cpd.added_date) AS week_no,COUNT(cpd.result) AS death_count
FROM cron_players_data cpd WHERE cpd.player_id = 81
AND cpd.result = 2 AND cpd.status = 1
GROUP BY WEEK(cpd.added_date);
```

Query output result screen

[image]

**Result Required**

```
23,24,25 AS week_no 2,3,1 AS death_count
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
select
  group_concat(t.week_no) as Weeks,
  group_concat(t.death_count) as DeathCounts
from (SELECT
    WEEK(cpd.added_date) AS week_no,
    COUNT(cpd.result) AS death_count
      FROM cron_players_data cpd
      WHERE cpd.player_id = 81
      AND cpd.result = 2
      AND cpd.status = 1
      GROUP BY WEEK(cpd.added_date)) as t
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this *alternative* solution:

Query

```
select group_concat( week_no ) as week_no, group_concat( death_count ) as death_count
from (
    SELECT WEEK(cpd.added_date) AS week_no,COUNT(cpd.result) AS death_count
    FROM cron_players_data cpd WHERE cpd.player_id = 81
    AND cpd.result = 2 AND cpd.status = 1
    GROUP BY WEEK(cpd.added_date)
) grouped_data
;
```